# java spark withColumn Binding attribute error

Tags: apache-spark

"TreeNodeException: Binding attribute, tree: visit_datetime#161" error occur when invoke spark udf in java

spark version : '2.3.0'
java version : '1.8.0'

**java pseudo-code**

```java
udfs.put(function.name + "3", udf((String a, Boolean b, Boolean c) -> "hello", DataTypes.StringType));
udfs.put(function.name + "5", udf((String a, String b, String c, Boolean d, Boolean e) -> "world", DataTypes.StringType));

UserDefinedFunction udf = (UserDefinedFunction)udfs.get(function.name + seq.length());
if (udf != null) {
   tableDataSet = tableDataSet.withColumn(column + "_", udf.apply(seq));
}

tableDataSet.explain(true);
tableDataSet.show(5);
```

**error message :**

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't find visit_datetime#161 in [outpatient_visit_id#0,outpatient_no#1,patient_id#2,dom_hospital_no#3,outpatient_visit_count#4,cdt_visit_doctor#5,cdt_visit_doctor_id#6,cdt_visit_department#7,cdt_visit_dept_speciality#8,cdt_visit_dept_code#9,rstd_visit_dept_name#10,rstd_visit_dept_code#11,rstd_visit_speciality#12,cdt_visit_type#13,visit_datetime#14,clinic_document_id#15,patient_age#16,cdt_fee_type#17,cdt_register_status#18,birth_date#19,registered_dept#20,registered_dept_code#21,registered_speciality#22,rstd_regist_dept_name#23,rstd_regist_dept_code#24,rstd_regist_speciality#25,selected_doctor#26,selected_doctor_id#27,time_of_register#28,triage_time#29,tirage_nurse#30,triage_nurse_id#31,yidu_mapping_source#32,yidu_register_status#33,yidu_visit_type#34,yidu_data_credibility#35,first_or_further_visit#36,visit_dept_code#37,clinic_type#38]

== Physical Plan ==

!Project [trim(outpatient_visit_id#0, None) AS outpatient_visit_id#361, trim(outpatient_no#1, None) AS outpatient_no#401, trim(patient_id#2, None) AS patient_id#441, trim(dom_hospital_no#3, None) AS dom_hospital_no#481, trim(outpatient_visit_count#4, None) AS outpatient_visit_count#521, trim(cdt_visit_doctor#5, None) AS cdt_visit_doctor#561, trim(cdt_visit_doctor_id#6, None) AS cdt_visit_doctor_id#601, trim(cdt_visit_department#7, None) AS cdt_visit_department#641, trim(cdt_visit_dept_speciality#8, None) AS cdt_visit_dept_speciality#681, trim(cdt_visit_dept_code#9, None) AS cdt_visit_dept_code#721, trim(rstd_visit_dept_name#10, None) AS rstd_visit_dept_name#761, trim(rstd_visit_dept_code#11, None) AS rstd_visit_dept_code#801, trim(rstd_visit_speciality#12, None) AS rstd_visit_speciality#841, trim(cdt_visit_type#13, None) AS cdt_visit_type#881, trim(UDF(visit_datetime#14, false, true), None) AS visit_datetime#921, trim(clinic_document_id#15, None) AS clinic_document_id#961, trim(UDF(patient_age#16, visit_datetime#161, birth_date#201, false, true), None) AS patient_age#1001, trim(cdt_fee_type#17, None) AS cdt_fee_type#1041, trim(cdt_register_status#18, None) AS cdt_register_status#1081, trim(UDF(birth_date#19, false, true), None) AS birth_date#1121, trim(registered_dept#20, None) AS registered_dept#1161, trim(registered_dept_code#21, None) AS registered_dept_code#1201, trim(registered_speciality#22, None) AS registered_speciality#1241, trim(rstd_regist_dept_name#23, None) AS rstd_regist_dept_name#1281, ... 15 more fields]